# The lower bound of the minimal eigen value

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\lambda_0$ be the minimal eigen value of positive difinte matrix $H$.If we have another matrix $H_0$ such that $\lVert H_0 - H \rVert_2 \leq \frac{\lambda_0}{4}$,then the minimal eigen value of $H_0$ is greater or equal to $\frac{3}{4}\lambda_0$.

This question arose when i read the proof of lemma 3.1 in following paper.

GRADIENT DESCENT PROVABLY OPTIMIZES OVER-PARAMETERIZED NEURAL NETWORKS

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably everything is nice and symmetric, then
$\lambda_0 I \le H = H_0 + H-H_0 \le H_0 + \|H-H_0\| I \le H_0 + \lambda_0 {1 \over 4} I$.
Hence $H_0 \ge \lambda_0 {3 \over 4} I$ and so all eigenvalues are $\ge \lambda_0 {3 \over 4}$.

Comment: nice answer，thanks.